# Setting up multiple Hadoop clusters

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hadoop

Hopefully this question isn't off topic. I asked this on AskUbuntu but haven't gotten a responses:

I've followed Michael Noll's excellent guide to get Hadoop set up on a single cluster: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

I'd now like to get a second node set up to do some processing. In this guide, and all others I've seen, these other clusters are all on the same LAN. However, I am doing my project using a Virtual Machine that I was given by my university that I access using PuTTY by connecting to its IP address. Can I connect this machine, across Hadoop, to a different machine on an entirely different IP address? Is this even possible? I tried editing the /etc/hosts of both computers and storing the IP address like this:

117.118.45.205:127.0.0.1 localhost

With the real IP address first, then the "local" IP address after, but that didn't work. Does anybody have any suggestions, or is this simply not possible?

Comment: please (for the love of sanity) read some documentation. Start with [`man man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man), and after that [the man page for `/etc/hosts`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts) which explains the syntax for that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, your edit of `/etc/hosts` is wrong. Add the public IP on a second line, don't use a colon to separate IPs like that. That syntax won't be understood.

Two, (I believe) if the second computer can ping the first, and vice-versa, it can be set up as a node in the Hadoop cluster. If not, then not. There may be issues related to going across a routing boundary (if you do so), but I don't have sufficient experience to be certain of that.

Comment: Another issue I should have mentioned is that whilst the first machine I can only access through PuTTY, the second machine is a Ubuntu installation accessed through Oracle Virtual Box, so it would be an IP address within an IP address.

Comment: Then you will have to change your Virtual Box networking to bridged and get a real IP. It is still not "an IP address within an IP address" - things don't work that way.